# Re-usable while loop function isn't looping

Tags: javascript, while-loop, functional-programming

Still a little new to javascript so this might be an easy fix but could anyone tell me why the following code does not work?
I am trying to create a reusable function that will increment from count to countTo in increments of countBy. I would like to vary those increments (either all evens, all odds, only numbers divisible by 5, etc). Right now it is just printing out -10 and not looping. Also it doesn't know count exists unless i make it global and I'm not sure why. 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: initialized count with count = 0, it works now. I'm still not sure why it doesn't just recognize the value of count when i pass it in as an argument though. Are they not the same "count"?

```
//count = incrementing variable
//countTo = final result
//countBy = how we should increment count
var count;
function looping(count, countTo, countBy) {
    while(count <= countTo) {
        console.log(count);
        count = countBy(count);
    }
}
console.log("-10 to 19");
var counting1 = looping(-10, 19, function () {
    return count++;
});
```

Comment: it should be -- looping(-10, 19, function (count) {
    return count++;
});

Comment: The `count` inside of the function `looping` is a local variable, which overrides the global `count` within the scope of `looping`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with `functional-programming` I'll answer it using functional techniques.

Where you went wrong

```
var count;
function looping(count, countTo, countBy) {
    // because you named a parameter `count`, you shadowed the external `count` variable
    while(count <= countTo) {
        console.log(count);
        // this doesn't reassign outer count
        // instead it reassigns local count and is discarded after function exits
        count = countBy(count);
    }
}
```

Functional programming advises against things like this tho anyway – and in some languages, it's outright impossible to do. External state is discouraged and variable reassignment is usually an indicator for problems. Let's start by adjusting how the code *should* work

```
var count; // no need for external state
var counting1 = looping(-10, 19, function (count) { // use local parameter
    return count++; // ++ is a mutating function
    return count + 1
});
```

Instead of relying upon external state, `count`, we will pass `count` into the function each loop. And rather than using `count++`, although it would work in JavaScript since numbers are already immutable, it's better to get in the habit of using non-mutating functions. Also `count + 1` makes it clear that a mutation is not necessary here and things like `count + 2` would work if we wanted to count by twos – or `count * 2` if we wanted to double the counter each time, etc.

To make this work, it's actually quite easy. Below is a recursive function which continues looping until `from` is greater than `to`. Each loop will send the current counter value into the callback, `f`, which is expected to return the next value of the counter.

```js
function looping (from, to, f) {
  if (from > to)
    return from
  else
    return looping (f (from), to, f)
}

looping (-3, 3, function (count) {
  console.log (count)
  return count + 1 // count by 1
})
// -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
// => 3

looping (-3, 3, function (count) {
  console.log (count)
  return count + 2 // count by 2
})
// -3, -1, 1, 3
// => 3
```

There's nothing wrong with using a `while`-loop, but it's important to keep any mutable state *localized* to the `looping` function. The important lesson here is that the *usage* of our function looks exactly the same and even tho the implementation changed, there are still no side effects.

```js
function looping (from, to, f) {
  while (from < to) from = f (from)
  return from
}

looping (-3, 3, function (count) {
  console.log (count)
  return count + 1 // count by 1
})
// -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
// => 3

looping (-3, 3, function (count) {
  console.log (count)
  return count + 2 // count by 2
})
// -3, -1, 1, 3
// => 3
```

Comment: I think somebody went on a downvoting spree. All the answers on this question were downvoted. Good explanation though. Love the fact that you used `<pre><code>` for creating rich text code blocks. Got to try that sometime, so +1 for that.

Comment: @AaditMShah thanks. I think `<pre><code>` is great for formatting syntax. Sadly it means the code cannot be executable tho :(

Answer (score -1):

`count` doesn't have a value by the time you increment it, hence it becomes `NaN`.

Comment: initialized count with count = 0, it works now. I'm still not sure why it doesn't just recognize the value of count when i pass it in as an argument though. Are they not the same "count"?

Answer (score -1):

You are making a simple function complex by using inline function call which is not correct. If question is about how to get this functionality, here is simple solution.

```
function looping(count, countTo, countBy) {
    while(count <= countTo) {
        console.log(count);
        count += countBy;
    }
}
console.log("-10 to 19");
var step = 2;
var counting1 = looping(-10, 19, step);
```

Comment: actually, this is what i did originally, but i also wanted to be able to count only even numbers (even when starting on an odd) or only numbers divisible by 5 etc. So i ended up using a function as an argument to get more versatility.